# How scrape information from a website

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have managed to navigate a website and make selections but now I need to scrape the information into my sheet and I am unsure how to proceed. The HTML is as follows:-

```
<div id="VisibleVehicles" class="filtered-vehicles">

                                                <div class="vehicle box-shadow-dark-2" data-id="86"
                                                     data-vehiclegroup="T"
                                                     data-vehicletitle="KIA PICANTO"
                                                     data-vehicleluggage="1"
                                                     data-vehicledoors="5"
                                                     data-vehiclepassengers="4"
                                                     data-vehicletransmission="M"
                                                     data-vehcileaircon="&#10004;"
                                                     data-standardwaiverratefee="4032.00"
                                                     data-superwaiverratefee="5216.00"
                                                     data-carsize="1"
                                                     data-transmission="manual"
                                                     data-vehicleaccriscode="MDMR"
                                                     data-norder="1">
                                                    <div class="vehicle-image">
                                                        <h4>
                                                            Group <text class="vehicle-group">T</text><br />
                                                            <text class="vehicle-title">KIA PICANTO
```

The information I need is vehiclegroup, vehicletitle, standardwaiverratefee, superwaiverratefee. I assume you use `.getElementsByClassName("filtered - vehicles")` but I do not know how iterate through that to obtain the information I require.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Shahin T, Kia Picanto, 4032.00 , 5216.00

Comment: One more thing to know: does this `class="vehicle box-shadow-dark-2"` class name changes, as in `-dark-2`,`-dark-3` etc.

Comment: @Shahin No " vehicle box-shadow-dark-2" stays the same with all the vehicles. Does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it and let me know what does it print in those respective columns. As i could not have the opportunity to play around with that real web. This one is hypothetical:

```
Dim post As Object
For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("filtered-vehicles")(0).getElementsByClassName("vehicle box-shadow-dark-2")
   R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.getAttribute("data-vehiclegroup")
   Cells(R, 2) = post.getAttribute("data-vehicletitle")
   Cells(R, 3) = post.getAttribute("data-standardwaiverratefee")
   Cells(R, 4) = post.getAttribute("superwaiverratefee")
Next post
```

Btw, the above code is meant to be used for IE not with xmlhttp request.

Comment: Thanks just had to change Cells(R, 1) to Cells(R, 1).Value. Help greatly appreciated.